# PostgreSQL - Foreign Key referencing multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I've got this problem at a postgres database.
I have four tables of location data (hospitals, schools, markets and police precints), slightly different between themselves, and a event report table that has a location column, referencing a location.

How can I make this reference, to a id that can be in any of the location tables?
I've tried to reference a parent table of them all, but inserts return an error of "key not present at table"

Thanks

Comment: Your approach is correct - you need a parent location table. When exactly is this error appearing?

Comment: When I try to insert data in the event report table. Since the data is in the children tables, the dbms can't find the id referenced at the parent table

Comment: If you work with PostgreSQL's inheritance, this is known limitation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS

Comment: Make a parent table without using the PostgreSQL's inheritance. Then you can refer to it from all the children and from the event report table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Kouber Saparev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83108/kouber-saparev)'s suggestion, I've removed the inheritance and used foreign keys to reference the parent from the children. It's working perfectly now.

Comment: What does this look like from the OO modeling side of things? How are you defining/working with these models in your application?